# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with IF

Tags: mysql

I have `sy_version` table which has a 2-column primary key: `(mod_id, sub_mod)`:

```
CREATE TABLE `sy_version` (
`mod_id` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`sub_mod` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`version` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`remark` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`update_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`download_link` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`file` BLOB NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`mod_id`, `sub_mod`)
)COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And my data is

```
CS;sbm_sl.exe;2015.11.01;IBS Sales App;2015-11-10 11:34:13;\N;0x73002E00000000
```

I want to update my data using `insert into on duplicate key`, for the first it is working fine. But everytime I executed I get my `file` column become `NULL`, result that I want is : file becomes `NULL` when version where I want to set is bigger the present(original) version. And the command is like below:

```
INSERT INTO sbm_sys.sy_version (mod_id,sub_mod,`version`,remark,update_date,file) 
values ('CS','sbm_sl.exe','2015.11.07.1','IBS Sales App','2015-11-10 11:34:13', NULL) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `version`='2015.11.07.1', remark='IBS Sales App', 
update_date='2015-11-10 11:34:13', file=if(VALUES(version)>version,null,file) ;
```

It doesn't work fine, `file` column does not become `NULL` but the other columns is updated, so I tried changing the part become, and it works as I hoped:

```
file=if(VALUES(version)>version,null,file) ==> file=if(VALUES(version)>'2015.11.01',null,file) ;
```

The question is how I can't get "2015.01.01" from original version value?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try this change:

```
INSERT INTO sbm_sys.sy_version
    (mod_id, sub_mod, version, remark, update_date, `file`) 
VALUES 
    ('CS', 'sbm_sl.exe', '2015.11.07.1', 'IBS Sales App', '2015-11-10 11:34:13', NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `file` = IF(VALUES(version) > version, NULL, `file`),    -- first this column
    version = VALUES(version),                               -- then this one
    remark = VALUES(remark), 
    update_date = VALUES(update_date) ;
```

The order of the columns matters, rather unfortunately and in contrast with the SQL standard. The [MySQL `UPDATE` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/update.html) states:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value. **This behavior differs from standard SQL.**
>
> `UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;`
>
> Single-table `UPDATE` assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. ...

Comment: This made may day. Been banging my head on this one for a few hours.

Comment: Thanks for this..., I needed an answer to this exact question.

Comment: As @ypercube stated, be careful about the ordering. If you need complex conditions, evaluate the whole condition first and then update, otherwise it will lead to inconsistent data.