# How to update the date of existing records?

Tags: mysql

Can you help me ? I've searched a lot and haven't found anything similar to what I need to do, thanks!

I have a table with 4 columns (CPF, NAME, PHONE, DT_IMP)

I need to update the DT_IMP column to the latest date if I receive an existing record in the PHONE column.

Example:

It is like this...

12312312312|JOAO | **21912345678**|**2021-12-09**

If I receive the PHONE 21912345678 again to be imported, the date must be updated to the day of import.

12312312312|JOAO | **21912345678**|**2022-01-31**

Comment: [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121920/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-if)

Comment: *If I receive the PHONE 21912345678 again* ??? What do you receive completely? phone only? if so then what values should be placed into cpf and name if the phone is absent? if you receive all values then do you need to compare phone only and ignore if another values differs, or update them? describe the task completely. I think that REPLACE INTO may be more suitable solution.

Comment: Explain how this happens:  "If I receive".  An Insert?  A LOAD DATA?  Should the data be updated when _the same_ number is "received"?  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Keep in mind that `PHONE` column should be declared as `PRIMARY KEY`.

Follow below example:
Suppose we have below data and we are trying to insert a matching `PHONE` value which is `21912345678`.

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
CPF bigint ,
NAME varchar(30),
PHONE varchar(30) ,
DT_IMP date,
primary key PHONE(`PHONE`) );

insert into test_tbl values
(12312312312,'JOAO',21912345678,'2021-12-09'),
(12312312313,'JOAO',21912345679,'2021-12-10'),
(12312312314,'JOAO',21912345656,'2021-12-11');
```

Using:

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl (`CPF`,`NAME`,`PHONE`,`DT_IMP`)
VALUES (12312312315,'BEN',21912345678, '2022-01-31') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `DT_IMP`=VALUES(`DT_IMP`);
```

The result would be:

```
CPF           NAME     PHONE        DT_IMP
12312312312   JOAO   21912345678    2022-01-31
12312312313   JOAO   21912345679    2021-12-10
12312312314   JOAO   21912345656    2021-12-11
```

Now if you want other value to change like `CPF` or `NAME`.

Use:

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl (`CPF`,`NAME`,`PHONE`,`DT_IMP`)
    VALUES (12312312315,'BEN',21912345678, '2022-01-31') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `CPF`=VALUES(`CPF`),`NAME`=VALUES(`NAME`),`DT_IMP`=VALUES(`DT_IMP`);
```

> Result:
>
> ```
>     CPF          NAME     PHONE         DT_IMP
> 12312312313      JOAO   21912345679   2021-12-10
> 12312312314      JOAO   21912345656   2021-12-11
> 12312312315      BEN    21912345678   2022-01-31
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8beb6a47a1c70919ee6b37ce9fbba291)

Comment: Hi Ergest, using the idea you demonstrated here and consulting the documentation about the DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE feature I managed to understand how I can use it here the way I need to. Thank you very much!